# How do you create a link which when clicked takes you to a page and also opens a new tab going to another url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have a link which when clicked preforms two actions:

1. redirects the current tab of the browser to url A.
2. opens a new tab directing the browser to url B

How can I do this? Is there HTML for this? Should I use javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use javascript to achieve this, something along the lines of this:

```
$('#foo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal link behaviour so you can open a new window
    window.open('http://foo.com/new-page'); // open new tab
    window.location.assign($(this).prop('href')); // go to new page in current tab
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery

```
<a href='#' onclick="f();return false;">link</a> // add onclick event

<script>
function f(){
document.location='/a.html'; // open in same tab
window.open('/b.html','_blank'); // open new tab
}
</script>
```